# Can't get EntityFunctions.TruncateTime() to work

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-functions

I am using Entity Framework Code First. Using LINQ to Entity I want to grab a record based on a DateTime value. Here is my current code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A method to check and see if the Parsed Game already exists on the
/// database. If Yes, then True is returned, otherwise False is returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The Db Context to use</param>
/// <param name="homeTeam">The Name of the Home Team for the Game.</param>
/// <param name="awayTeam">The Name of the Away Team for the Game.</param>        
/// <param name="date">The Date of the Game</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool doesGameAlreadyExist(PContext context, String homeTeam, String awayTeam, String date)
{
    string dtObjFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, dtObjFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    var result = context.Games.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Start) == dt.Date).FirstOrDefault();
    return result != null;

}
```

The above code throws the following error:

```
    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] TruncateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I also tried the following code, and I get the same error:

```
var result = context.Games.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Start) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dt.Date)).FirstOrDefault();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very strange. This almost looks as if you had another static class `EntityFunctions` somewhere. What if you hit F12 on "EntityFunctions"? Do you land in `System.Data.Entity.dll` and `System.Data.Objects` namespace?

Comment: I have the same problem - using alpha version of EF6

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I faced this problem recently when I upgraded my Web Application from Entity Framework 5 to Entity Framework 6. Then, I realized that `System.Data.Entity` DLL needs to be removed from the application completely in order to work with Entity Framework 6. Entity Framework 6 is not part of .NET Framework anymore and therefore it is independent of System.Data.Entity dll. In order to Truncate time, you would need to use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(...)` method from EntityFramework.dll. Yes, that solved my problem.

**Bottom Line** : If you are using Entity Framework 6, first REMOVE the reference `System.Data.Entity` DLL and then, in your code, replace `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(..)` with `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(...)`. [ From EntityFramework.dll ]

Comment: If you are already using `EntityFunctions` then you are probably importing the System.Data.Entity namespace.  So just removing the System.Data.Entity v4.0 assembly reference and replacing `EntityFunctions` with `DbFunctions` in code should work for most people.

Comment: If want to put .Include().. i still need System.Data.Entity. Is Include exists in EntityFramework.dll version 6+ ?

Answer (score 11):

I didn't remove the reference `System.Data.Entity`, I just changed the call from `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` to `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and it worked for me.

I'm using Entity 6.

Comment: Thanks @Nour. I'm glad for help!

Comment: that's the same thing

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Parse(sText);
campaigns = _CampaignMasterRepository.Get().OrderByDescending(a => a.LaunchOn).Where(a => a.UserId == obj_User.ID && a.CampaignStatus == (int)OmevoEnums.CampaignStatus.Sent && a.CampaignName.Contains(sText) || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.LaunchOn) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt)).ToList();
```

For getting the date results through Linq queries use this function.